Create deck of multiple decks of cards using list comprehension

I've created a Card object:
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit, d=0): 
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.deck_index = d

I can make a list of Cards that represents a standard deck, using list comprehension:
ranks = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
suits = ['hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds', 'spades']
deck = ([Card(r, s) for r in ranks for s in suits] + 
        [Card('Joker', 'black'), Card('Joker', 'red')])

I'd like to create a list of Cards that represents N decks combined, using list comprehension.

I can do it with a for loop:
decks = []
for i in range(N):
    decks += ([Card(r, s, d=i) for r in ranks for s in suits] +
              [Card('Joker', ' black', i), Card('Joker', 'red', i)])


But if I write this loop as a list comprehension, I get a list of lists, instead of a list of cards:
decks = [[Card(r, s, d=i) for r in ranks for s in suits] + 
         [Card('Joker', 'black', i), Card('Joker', 'red', i)] 
         for i in range(N)]

I tried putting the target in parentheses and unpacking it with *. I got the error:
Iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension
I could use list comprehension for the deck without Jokers and add the Jokers separately with their own list comprehensions:
decks = ([Card(r, s, i) for r in ranks for s in suits for i in range(N)] + 
         [Card('Joker', 'black', i) for i in range(N)] + 
         [Card('Joker', 'red', i) for i in range(N)])

But this redundantly specifies the loop three times.
It also puts Jokers at the end, instead of preserving the original order with Jokers next to the cards from their own deck. This point isn't too important because I shuffle in my next step, but I would like to know if it's possible to combine the decks with order preserved using list comprehension.

I'd state the general problem like this:
lst = lst1 + lst2 is a list of elements
lsts = [lst1(i) + lst2(i) for i in range(N)] is a list of lists
How can I use list comprehension to create a list of elements in lst1(i) + lst2(i) for i in range(N)?
The solution's likely available online but I don't know what words to search for. "Combine sums of lists using list comprehension" gives list comprehension tutorials and how to sum lists elementwise.
One option I found is to let it make a list of lists and then flatten that using sum(lst,[]) (slow) or list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst)) (fast). But can I avoid making a list of lists?

"I can do it with a for loop" - So what's wrong with that?

PEP8 exists for good reason, please don't come up with creative code formatting to save space, the 80s are over. You'll find that code formatted according to convention is easier to read for yourself and others, and it will save you time wasted reformatting other people's code, like it will for them with regard to your code. Also, what's N?

Try using a helper function to express the logic for a single deck; you'll get a much more readable result that way. However, you'll still need the same techniques to get a flat result from embedding that list in another list comprehension. Please see the linked duplicates, according to your overall approach.

@KarlKnechtel Do any of those old questions/answers really address this? Note the OP already linked to one of them and ruled that out, as they want something more direct. And none of the answers of the other one seem to apply, either.

@Grismar N is the number of decks I'd like to combine into one deck. It could be set to a user-specified integer. In my case it'll probably be 1, 2, or 3.

@nocomment yes, because it's general programming technique. We don't deal in "direct", if you mean "separately tailored to each person who asks regarding an individual code base". Please keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum but a Q&A site; the purpose is to answer the question. Please check meta.stackoverflow.com to understand more about what is considered a duplicate here and about the site's purpose generally.

And yes, my first duplicate is specifically about writing "nested" list comprehensions (multiple-clause ones, not one inside another) so as to get a flat result without making intermediate lists. However, making those intermediate lists is often faster in Python.

@KarlKnechtel No I mean "direct" as in "without creating multiple lists and then flattening them", which you seem to propose and which they don't want and which is wasteful and unnecessary.

Again: see the first duplicate link I proposed, which explicitly is about exactly that. I separately proposed, in the comments, creating multiple lists, because it is not necessarily less efficient (and can sometimes allow for more elegant code).]

@KarlKnechtel Again: none of the answers there seem to apply (I had looked through all of them). The accepted/top-voted answer in particular is about using multiple for clauses, which the OP of this question already knows and used. I think you're missing the issue here.

I'm aware that OP's code already uses multiple for clauses. But the solution is still to "use multiple for clauses", but in a way that actually addresses the substance of the problem. "How do I do something twice?" doesn't become a different question from "how do I do something?" just because the order matters. It's a question of understanding how the multiple-clause for works (which is more than adequately explained over there) and applying reasoning to that understanding to solve the problem (we answer questions, we don't solve problems).

@KarlKnechtel So which of those answers suffice for this case?

I did read the duplicate before posting. But I didn't see how it could be used for my case.
I re-read it now and see I could do [card for i in range(N) for card in deck(i)]. I used @nocomment's Attempt This Online link to test it and it seems to work.

@WeCanDoItGuys What does deck(i) return, though? If it returns a list, that's pretty much the same downside as the "list of lists" that you asked to avoid.

def deck(i): return [Card(r, s, i) for r in ranks for s in suits] + [Card('Joker', 'black', i), Card('Joker', 'red', i)]

Surprisingly due to the ordering of the list comprehension it doesn't make a list of lists. Attempt this online!

It doesn't create a list of lists but it still creates those lists which you then flatten. Didn't you want to avoid that? That's what your question's last half paragraph seems to say.

@Kelly the first dupe target was spot on. Why did you unhammer this?

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні No. That target involved having a black box function producing lists and flattening them into one list, which this question seeks to avoid. Also, due to the two kinds of cards (normal and jokers) it's not as simple as what all those answers there do.

This creates the same as your "for loop" solution:
decks = [
    Card(r, s, i)
    for i in range(N)
    for rs, ss in [
        (ranks, suits),
        (['Joker'], ['black', 'red'])
    ]
    for r in rs for s in ss
]

Attempt This Online!
Since my list with the two "product specifications" is the same for every i, it could be built once beforehand and (re)used for each i. But it's relatively small compared to the overall work/output, so I kept it simple.

May I know what's the issue with this, so I can address it? Like I said it produces the expected result, the testing is linked to, and as far as I see, this fits what the question asks for.

Thanks for the Attempt this Online link, I used it to test the duplicate question solution. Result

It does fit what the question asks for and it's neat but I was waiting to accept it in case  more answers were given. It seems Karl Knechtel's linked answer is less verbose although a bit harder to see what's going on.

@WeCanDoItGuys That builds lists and then copies their elements to the result list. Isn't your question about avoiding that?

It does, your code wins on that front. But it's also a type of list comprehension I didn't know I could do (putting the meaty stuff at the end and the outer loop in the middle). It keeps the concept of a "deck" grouped together and I like that for code readability and editing. I'll mark yours as correct since yours makes the fewest unnecessary lists.
